# Prevent small signal with noise

Tags: noise, conductivity

I am designing a Conductivity Meter by using Arduino.

I used ad9850 to generate a sin wave with 1khz and peak to peak 20mV.

but there is a bit of noise with my output Signal
[image]
and after the voltage follower , The noise have been amplified
by voltage follower.(as shown below)
[image]

**What I've Tried**

I thought maybe I can use RC filter to get a clean sin wave(you can see the detail in two video link I post below), but I still have to put my out put Signal to another voltage follower.

Does anyone have good suggestion to filter the noise?
This is my Circuit：
[image]
before RC filter：

https://www.dropbox.com/s/22808bem0uizszn/rc%E6%BF%BE%E6%B3%A2%E5%89%8D.mp4?dl=0

after RC filter：

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xebs8p84kpcm5q/rc%E6%BF%BE%E6%B3%A2%E5%BE%8C.mp4?dl=0

------------update at 2018/11/25

@WhatRoughBeast  , I have conducted an experiment
to make sure that the noise from my output signal is coming from my power supply .
The following link is my experiment video, I used 1kohm/0.1uF RC filter to keep
the noise out of my power supply.(which is similar function with the scheme you told me)

In oscilloscope of my video, The yellow line wave was measured across 1k ohm and 0.1uF.

The blue line wave  was measured across only 0.1uF capacitance.
I was wondering that the does the yellow line running like a sin wave is really the switching noise affecting my output signal?
Did my 1k/0.1F RC filter completely keep the noise out of my DC power? 
It seems that the blue line is still floating because of some low-frequency.
Please see the detail in the following link and picture, thank you!
[image]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0t1wef1mmjqot2a/%E6%BF%BE%E9%99%A4%E5%8E%9F%E4%B9%8B%E9%9B%9C%E8%A8%8A%E5%AF%A6%E9%A9%97.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Show us your circuit and describe your power supplies.

Comment: How are you probing?

Comment: @DaveTweed
,This is the circuit I am using now  
http://tinyurl.com/ybx4oq2o

Comment: @Jeroen3
This is the probe I used to measured the signal

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2fn700trfaeozn/%E7%A2%B3%E6%A3%92%E7%A4%BA%E6%84%8F%E5%9C%96.PNG?dl=0

Comment: the power supplies with which I used for AD9850 is from the +5v pin of Arduino

Comment: The dropbox and tinyurl links are not useful. Please edit the information directly into your question.

Comment: Dave Tweed , thank for your advise , I just added my circuit on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is my Circuit：

No, it's not.

1) You show two different frequencies (1 kHz and 8 kHz) being applied. However, your scope FFT shows only a single frequency.

2) There is no sign of the 100 ohm/1 ohm divider.

3) The output of the RC filter seems to be coupled to the scope via another capacitor which is not shown. (Hint - there is no need to do this if you're looking at a small AC signal with a large DC offset. Simply change your scope input coupling from DC to AC. That sort of thing is exactly why the option exists.)

Additionally, you have no decoupling of your op amp power supplies, and any switching noise on the power supply will run through op amp like grease through a goose.

In general, you should use the long horizontal bus strips (like the two you've used for the power supply) for ground as well. At each IC, connect the vertical strips just below pins 4 and 5 of the IC to the ground strip, using bits of bare wire just long enough to jump from point to point at each end of the strips. Avoid long loops like the plague. Then you should run a 0.1 uF cap directly from the IC pin strips to the local ground strip, and likewise make your input and output ground connections to this local strip. And for a low-current setup like this, you should add a 1 to 10 ohm resistor in series from the power supply to the decoupling cap/op amp connection.

Since your Arduino/AD9850 is running from a separate power supply, connect the ground of this supply at the local ground strip of the op amp. Do not connect it at the op amp power supply.

So, overall, you connection scheme should look something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSfy6s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, the darker line is the local ground area formed by the two strips just below pins 4 and 5.

Comment: (1)  I think that the real noise in my circuit is high-frequency , so I use 8khz as noise , and I try to use low-pass filter to get rid of it in my simulated circuit.
(2) sorry! , I didn't record my whole circuit in my video , There was actually a 100 ohm/1 ohm divider above the circuit .
(3) Because I want to get a sin wave which has negative peak to measure the Conductivity , I use a capacitor to filter out DC offset.
I was wondering the 100nF capacitor you put in your circuit, Did you put it to filter out the high-frequency noise?

Comment: @張恩典 - 1)Yes, both 100 nF caps help keep noise out of the power supply terminals. This is described in my answer. Please read and pay attention. 2) A single-stage RC filter will not do much to suppress 8 KHz while passing 1 KHz, so don't expect much. And, for what it's worth, the noise spikes on your scope traces do indeed contain much higher frequencies, and 8 KHz is not a reasonable representation.

Comment: I am now confuosed by a problem ,what is the different between this two king of the setup ?
http://tinyurl.com/y8qln8gl
I thought that as for the input of op amp , it still got the same electrical potential difference,  
Does it matters that I should put the ground of signal and power supply at same point?

Comment: @張恩典 - In principle there is no difference. When 2 components are in series (and no other connection is made to the connecting point), the order of the components doesn't matter. It's like the difference between 3 x 4 and 4 x 3. With that said, you should always connect the ground of an instrument to a common point - don't let power supplies float. There may be other current paths available, such as through the AC lines. So yes, always (if possible) connect your power supply grounds and signal grounds to the same point. If that point includes the AC power line you may kill yourself - be warned

Comment: I have updated an new experiment in my question to make sure where the noise comes from ,  could you see the update at 2018/11/25 ? thx!

Comment: @張恩典 - I can't really tell what's going on. Your timebase is so slow that it is impossible to see if the spikes in your first two photos are still there. As for the low-frequency behavior, your scope traces are jumping all over the place, amplitude is varying by at least 30%, and your envelope shows some very odd relatively fast changes. All of this at 10 mV levels. In other words, I have no idea what environment you're working in, but it's not a good one. What I will say is that I've never experienced a switching power supply produce this sort of behavior.

Comment: I didnt put spikes (my two first photos ) in my curcuit , I only put the 15v DC power as my input to my curcuit now , and oberseve the whether or not it is a clean DC power for my op amp.

Comment: @張恩典 - Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean or what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain my question very well , I will try your circuit to solve my problem . It's greatly appreciated. Thx.